# Permutations and recurrence equation

Tags: combinatorics, permutation, difference-equations

First problem:
I need to show all Permutations with length  4 of this elements `{x, y, z, w, t}` but with this condition: the element z mustn't be after element t. I tryed this :

```
A = {x, y, z, w, t}
Permutations[A, {4 }]
```

But don't know how to remove those permutations in which z is after t.

Second problem:
I have a recurrence equation in which i have to print the first 11 member of the sequence a which are the answers of the equation but they don't have the digit 3 in their number.

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == 11*a[n], a[1] == 7}, a[n], {n, 1, 11}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a reasonable number of items, make them all and delete the ones you don't want.

```
A = {x, y, z, w, t};
DeleteCases[Permutations[A, {4}], {___, t, ___, z, ___}]
```

Comment: yeah but i have a lot to delete isn't there any function  to delete them all at once ?

Comment: @Vlatko I don't understand.  How can you "have a lot to delete"?  There are only 84 cases and it takes (on a Mac Pro) just 0.000157 seconds to compute them all.

Comment: Sry i didn't wrote the function at first the right way it works perfectly thank you very much ::))

Answer (score 2):

For your second problem, use `IntegerDigits`, `MemberQ` and `Select` to find elements of the sequence that do not `(!MemberQ[...,3])` have a 3 digit ...

```
Select[RecurrenceTable[{a[n+1]==11*a[n],a[1]==7}, 
 a[n], {n,1,11}],!MemberQ[IntegerDigits@#,3]&]

 (* results {7, 77, 847, 102487, 12400927, 1500512167, 181561972207} *)
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked perfectly :))

Answer (score 0):

Just for variety (for second part):

```
f[n_] := Nest[11 # &, 7, n - 1]
q[n_] := Times @@ Unitize[IntegerDigits[n] - 3];
lst = f /@ Range[11];
```

Approaches:

```
Reap[Sow[f@#, q@(f@#)] & /@ Range[11], 1, #2 &][[2, 1]]
Pick[lst, q /@ lst, 1]
1 /. GroupBy[lst, q]
```

All yield:

```
{7, 77, 847, 102487, 12400927, 1500512167, 181561972207}
```